# Error EPERM offlinefirst.sock

Tags: javascript, express

When trying to run https://github.com/jakearchibald/wittr on windows bash I get the following error and help with either fixing it or debugging it would be very much appreciated:

```
 Development server listening. (PID:469)
 Config server listening at localhost:8001
 Server listening at localhost:8000
 events.js:141
       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
       ^

 Error: listen EPERM offlinefirst.sock
     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
     at Server._listen2 (net.js:1237:19)
     at listen (net.js:1286:10)
     at Server.listen (net.js:1376:5)
     at Server._listen (/mnt/d/wittr/build/server/Server.js:327:25)
     at Server.setConnectionType (/mnt/d/wittr/build/server/Server.js:353:14)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/wittr/build/server/index.js:27:8)
     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

Answer (score 2):

It will run when you move `wittr` directory to your linux home `~/`.

Comment: what's the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest solution is to use Node.js v4.
I had the same problem and it works for me with v4 on Windows (not WSL, haven't tried it).

Comment: tried downgrading, no luck - thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: Don't forget to delete node_modules when downgrading or switching between Windows and WSL :)